# Problems on IBM transfer access

Tags: xlsx, transfer

I've got a problem using data transfer on IBM-I (version 1.1.8.2). Using a DTTX to transfer (insert) new data on a AS400 table from an xlsx file.
I 've found that the original content of the table on AS400 was completely cleared.
The transfer was confirmed on a window with the number of records present in the xlsx file but after that only my freshly transferred records were present.

Has anyone reported such a problem?

Thanks

.. previously explained